# Calling methods from constructor

Tags: java

I've tried researching this question but I am a beginner and am not sure on the correct wording of it, so I am sorry if this is not a good question.

I am creating a CustomerGUI class for one of my tabbed panes in my project and calling it from a main GUI class. What I would like to know is, when I create the CustomerGUI object, is it acceptable to call the createGUI method from the constructor? That way I would only have to write `tabbedPane("Customers", new CustomerGUI());`

Or would it be better to write `tabbedPane("Customers", new CustomerGUI().createGUI);` ?

Which would be best?

```
public class CustomerGUI {

public CustomerGUI() {

}

public JPanel createGUI() {
    JPanel panelCustomersMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panelCustomersMainGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    ...
```

Or

```
public class CustomerGUI {

public CustomerGUI() {
    createGUI();
}

public JPanel createGUI() {
    JPanel panelCustomersMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panelCustomersMainGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    ...
```

From what I understand, and please correct me if I am wrong, the constructor is used to set up variables for that instance of the class. However in my CustomerGUI class I don't have any variables that need to be set up, and I am using the constructor as a sort of entry point to start other methods like a main method. I just wanted to know if this was not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the answer depends on how your client classes use `CustomerGUI` instances.

- Case 1

If it makes sense for the client class to instantiate `CustomerGUI` at a time and to create effectively the components inside later, providing a public `createGUI()` method makes sense. It is a lazy init on client demand.
Note that a naming with a `void` return such as `void initGUI()` or `void init()` makes more sense and is probably clearer for clients.
`JPanel createGUI()` is ambiguous enough. With such a naming, client class may imagine that we could invoke it multiple times. Besides, the method returns something while it should not.  It should only init the object state.

---

As alternative for lazy loading, you could simply use `Supplier<CustomerGUI>` from client classes. In this way, the object is effectively created only as `Supplier.get()` is invoked.

---

- Case 2

On the other side, if the client class that instantiates `CustomerGUI` always needs to have all its components initialized in, `createGUI()` should not even be a public API, it should be defined as `private` and invoked by the constructor.

Comment: I want to add one thing to OP. `createGUI()` should not instantiate an arbitrary amount of `JPanel` objects, but only return one. This is error-prone and confusing. If you don't need the single `JPanel` that is returned, just change the return type of the method to `void`. If you need the single one, create an extra method for it.

Comment: @Georg Muehlenberg I agree with your totally. I was editing about :)